# how to fix swipe view list view issue of offset?

Tags: android, swipe, photoswipe

I am integrating issues while swipe in list view. 
in my list view if i swipe right to left in portrait time the view is

[image]

for this view i used below code

```
<com.fortysevendeg.swipelistview.SwipeListView
    xmlns:swipe="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/list_myproducts"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    app:swipeActionLeft="reveal"
    app:swipeCloseAllItemsWhenMoveList="true"
    app:swipeOffsetLeft="250dp"
    app:swipeOffsetRight="0dp"
    swipe:swipeBackView="@+id/back"
    swipe:swipeDrawableChecked="@drawable/ic_left"
    swipe:swipeDrawableUnchecked="@drawable/ic_left"
    swipe:swipeFrontView="@+id/front"
    swipe:swipeMode="left" />
```

but now while i ll use this screen for landscape mode at that time view is

[image]

As you can see that there is all data are goes left side and we are not able to see anything.
So any one can help me that how can i resolve this issues.

Comment: please add your code

Comment: @MHossein check my code

Comment: thanks. i want row of list layout code.

Comment: Hi sam! on orientation change find the width of screen and set the left offset programatically.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to modify

```
app:swipeOffsetLeft="250dp"
```

to smaller value

Comment: i tried but not working it will set offset from left and i need from right

Comment: For landscape, you may create another layout :)

Comment: :) same issue will occur while i go in low resolution screen. i tried this all.

Comment: I'm working with SwipeMenuListView, but i dont use this lib. For screen solution, i set offset in java class with dpToPx function :)

Comment: can you suggest me that thing. now i'gm thinking to do this dynamic by getting screen resolution. ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93567/discussion-between-sameer-donga-and-steve-luck).